# Can not set inline style based on model's value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, background-color, inline-styles

I am working with MVC 4. I want to use model's value to set inline-style. But It didn't work?

```
style= "background-color:@item.CompanyColor"//It not work
style= "background-color:Black"//It work: background color is black now
```

And I can use this value to set color like that:

```
font color="@item.CompanyColor"//it work: font color changed
```

So, what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Use parenthesis to separate code with style attribute.
It should be like this :

style= "background-color: @(item.CompanyColor) "

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Html.Raw html helper

```
style="background-color: @{Html.Raw(item.CompanyColor);}"
```